# Finds cells on multiple conditions and cut paste the same to another sheet (Simplified)

Tags: excel, vba

Any alternative or suggestions to Fasten the below stated code that finds cells on multiple conditions and cut paste the same to another sheet.

```
Sub test()
  'For Move Entire Row to New Worksheet if Cell Contains Specific Text's
  'Using autofilter to Copy rows that contain certain text to a sheet called commodity
  Dim LR As Long
  Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
  LR = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
  LR1 = Sheets("Commodity").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

  With Sheets("Data").Range("e:e")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=("*SILVER*")
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy 
    Destination:=Sheets("Commodity").Range("A" & LR1)
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
  End With

  With Sheets("Data").Range("e:e")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=("*GOLD*")
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy 
    Destination:=Sheets("Commodity").Range("A" & LR1)
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
  End With

  With Sheets("Data").Range("e:e")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=("*MCX*")
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy 
    Destination:=Sheets("Commodity").Range("A" & LR1)
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: you need to fully qualify `LR`, change to `LR = Sheets("Data").Cells(Sheets("Data").Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row`. Also,  `LR1` changes every time after you paste a range, so you need to re-find `LR1` after every paste.

Comment: sir any way i can reduce the time for the macro to complete as its taking lot of time.again any simplified version ?

Comment: use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in the beginning, and restore at the end with `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

Answer (score 0):

As well as the good suggestions @ShaiRado is making, what's slowing this down is your repeated interactions with the Excel functions and interface. Ideally, you'd read the data into variables within VBA, and then, all within VBA, check for matches and prepare an output array. That way you'd only have one interaction between VBA and Excel, namely to write the output array to your target sheet. It's also costly in time to delete one row at a time, so you might be better to create just one 'delete range' and hit it all in one go.

Skeleton code to achieve this is given below (but note, it will need a 'column offset' calculation if your used range doesn't start at "A", and you might choose a more reliable function than `UsedRange`). You call the routine like so:

```
TransferData "Silver", "Gold", "MCX"
```

And the routine itself might like something like this:

```
Private Sub TransferData(ParamArray searchItems() As Variant)
    Dim srcData As Variant
    Dim txData() As Variant
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim txIndexes As Collection
    Dim delRng As Range

    'Read source data into an array
    'Note: I've used UsedRange as I don't know your sheet layout
    srcData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Value2

    'Check for matches and record index number
    Set txIndexes = New Collection
    For r = 1 To UBound(srcData, 1)
        For Each item In searchItems
            If srcData(r, 5) = item Then
                txIndexes.Add r
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'Trasfer data to output array
    ReDim txData(1 To txIndexes.Count, 1 To UBound(srcData, 2))
    r = 1
    For Each item In txIndexes
        For c = 1 To UBound(srcData, 2)
            txData(r, c) = srcData(item, c)
        Next
        r = r + 1
    Next

    'Write the transfer data to target sheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Commodity")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Resize(UBound(txData, 1), UBound(txData, 2)) = txData
    End With

    'Delete the transfered rows
    For Each item In txIndexes
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
            If delRng Is Nothing Then
                Set delRng = .Cells(item, "A")
            Else
                Set delRng = Union(delRng, .Cells(item, "A"))
            End If
        End With
    Next
    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```